# Node.js / Mongoose / Sort & display in order

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I have a little problem to display a result set in original order.
My mongoose "query" is simply :

```
myCollection.find({}, null, {sort: {weight: 1}}, function (err, res) {
    //etc...
});
```

The log of res is good, my result is correctly sorted by weight asc.

I display the result with a forEach loop in an ejs template like this :

```
<% res.forEach(function(r) { %>
    <%= r.weight %>
<% }) %>
```

And it displays my result in a "pseudo-random" order ...
e.g : 2,3,4,1,9,10,6 ...

In my Schema, weight param is a Number

```
weight          : { type: Number, default: 0, required: false }
```

**UPDATE :**

I execute another query on the result, in a loop like that :

```
newResult = [];
async.each(res, function(r, callback) {
    // some actions with r ...
    newResult.push(r);
}, ....);
```

I construct a new list of objects in my loop and it's THIS list who is send to the view to display elements.

I think js reorder the array ...

Is it possible to keep the original order ?

Tks.
Appreciate your help. C.

Comment: What does `typeof(r.weight)` output inside your loop?

Comment: `typeof(r.weight)` returns "number"

Comment: Don't think I understand what's going on in the update - is that related to the original issue?

Comment: Yes, coz' it's the newResult var who is send to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @nabeel, your answer led me on the right way :)

The solution to reorder an array of objects with async is async.sortBy()

```
async.sortBy(newResult, function(n, callback){
    callback(err, n.sort.criteria);
}, function(err, results){
    callback(null, results);
});
```

results is now the sorted array

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it's not working for you. Please try like this...

```
myCollection.find()
  .sort("weight")
  .exec(function (err, res) {
    //etc...
});
```

**UPDATE**

`async.each` is an asynchronous function which means that the callbacks can be out of order. So if you don't want to lose the order of the array you should either use a simple for loop OR you can re-sort the array after `async.each` has finished.

Comment: Please share the schema

Comment: The schema is good, I think it's a js array problem. Please, check my answer update. Thanks for your help

Comment: Thank you. Is there a simple way to resort the array of objects? I think to use a callback in a for loop is not recommended.

Comment: You can use `_.each` which is synchronous so it won't mess up the order. And if you want to keep it async then use `_.sortBy` after `async.each`. 

http://underscorejs.org/#each,     
http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy